# Issue with formatting android text in textView

Tags: android, string, formatting, textview, formatter

I am having a lot of issues with formatting a string on a textView. I am creating a stopwatch app and I need to format it as "00:00:00" but when I start the stopwatch, it comes up as "00:00:000"

Here is the code

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
  updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
  int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
  int mins = secs / 60;
  secs = secs % 60;
  int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
  timerValue.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", mins, secs, milliseconds));
  customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}
```

};

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the fix you want is to make milliseconds 3 digits as it can be that many digits:

```
 "%02d:%02d:%03d"
```

"%02d" prepends zeros if the number is too short, but does not truncate it if it is too long.  Milliseconds can be a 3 digit value.

If you want the final value to be 2 digits you can do:

```
  milliseconds /= 10;  // now 1/100ths of a second
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't Milliseconds in 1/1000th of a second?
I think you need to displayed up to hundreth..
I think 00:00:000 is accurate in this case.